# JDBC batch delete statement.executeBatch() throw read-only transaction exception

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I use batch delete via JDBC statement batch update using Postgresql driver.

It throws `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot execute DELETE in a read-only transaction`

```
String childTableDelete = "delete from child c using parent p where p.id=c.p_id and p.expired=true";
String parentTableDelete = "delete from parent where expired=true";

try (final Connection connection = this.dataSource.getConnection();
                final Statement statement = connection.createStatement())
        {
            
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            
            statement.addBatch(childTableDelete);
            statement.addBatch(parentTableDelete);
            try
            {
                final int count[] = statement.executeBatch();
                connection.commit();                 
            }
            catch (final BatchUpdateException batchUpdateException)
            {
                connection.rollback();              
            }

        }
        catch (final SQLException exception)
        {
            eexception.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I am expecting all Childs records to be deleted that are associated with parent and then the parent records.

Comment: `this.dataSource.getConnection()` is, obviously, returning a connection that is in read-only mode. One way to do that is with `.setReadOnly`; but a DB can itself decide to do this (for example, if the user/pass you connect with does not have write rights). This question does not contain sufficient detail to provide any further answer than this.